# xaml to c# function, universal style or function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

hi everyone i have a xaml code like this

```
<Style x:Key = "{x:Type TabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" />
```

that code will aim every TabItem there in our program
please help me create some function like that, but not a xaml code, that is a C# code.
Which it C# code has a some function aim "Every TabItem" Created in the program.

Comment: What are you trying to _do_ with that C# function? Depending on what it is, there may be a simple way to do in XAML, rather than having to find some convoluted way to call C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a style to apply to all controls of a certain type setting the `TargetType` alone is enough in XAML, the `x:Key` is redundant (if it is set to anything other than the type of the control it will no longer apply automatically so i would omit it). To make sure this Style affects all controls in the entire application you need to add it at the root level, i.e. the App-class.

To get this done in code-behind i would probably override the `OnStartup` method:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Style myStyle = new Style(typeof(TabItem));
    // Style definitions...
    Resources.Add(typeof(TabItem), myStyle);
}
```